# Implementing more than one photobox gallery on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have setup photobox gallery and it works just fine except in the following scenario:
Suppose I implemented 2 galleries on the same page, 2nd gallery works just fine, but not the 1st one, because of the following code:

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function($) {
        $('#gallery').photobox('a.forImages');
        }
    )(jQuery);
```

Now, I have tried to include something like this, but in no vain, this code doesn't process what I want, actually not even 1st nor 2nd gallery works in this scenario. Is there any other way I can include that photobox is setup for every gallery div element on my page?

```
  jQuery.noConflict();
    (function($) {
        $('#galery').each(function() {
            (this).photobox('a.forImages');
            });

        // or with a fancier selector and some settings, and a callback:
   }
    )(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yes, but they each need a unique ID, or you can give them all classes and select by class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a class `gallery` instead of id

**html**

```
<div class = "gallery" id = "gallery1"/>
<div class = "gallery" id = "gallery2"/>
```

**javascript**

```
(function($){
    $('.gallery').photobox('a.forImages');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I have voted your A. however this thing with id gallery doesn't work, it includes all images from every gallery to one single gallery. Any other solution to this issue?

Comment: what do you mean, I'm not sure what the problem is, can you provide a fiddle or some code

Answer (score 2):

works well for me.

HTML

```
<div id="gallery1" class="gallery"/>
<div id = "gallery2" class="gallery"/>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var galeries = $("div[id^='gallery']");
    $.each(galeries, function(){
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).photobox('a'); 
    });
});
```